# Apportion number of days per month between two dates in R code?

Tags: r

I am very new to R programming and am trying to determine the number of days apportioned per month between two dates.

I have a dataset that has the following structure:
from_date
to_date
quantity

Example data:

```
2019-06-15 2019-09-10 55
2019-07-11 2019-10-05 17
```

I would like to call a function that returns a dataset/vector? that holds 3 values as there will be a maximum difference between from_date and to_date of 3 months.

I have tried using `lubridate::floor_date()` to work backward from the `to_date`

Comment: what is your desired output? Not clear about `call a function that returns a dataset/vector? that holds 3 values as there will be a maximum difference between from_date and to_date of 3 months.`

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the result you expect but I think it's a good start to find a solution.   
`df <- data.frame("from_date" = c("2019-06-15", "2019-09-10"),
                 "to_date" = c("2019-07-11", "2019-10-05"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

`df$quantity <- as.Date(as.character(df$to_date), format="%Y-%m-%d") - as.Date(as.character(df$from_date), format="%Y-%m-%d")`
This code allow you to know the number of days between two dates

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for some result like below:

```
df$quantity <-  with(df,as.Date(to_date)-as.Date(from_date))
```

or

```
df$quantity <- apply(df, 1, function(v) diff(as.Date(v)))
```

yielding

```
> df
   from_date    to_date quantity
1 2019-06-15 2019-09-10       87
2 2019-07-11 2019-10-05       86
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(from_date = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2019-06-15", 
"2019-07-11"), class = "factor"), to_date = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2019-09-10", 
"2019-10-05"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: If that is what OP really wants,  there is no need for `apply` there. `as.Date(df$to_date) - as.Date(df$from_date)`

Comment: Firstly, thank you to those that have commented, really appreciate you taking the time.

I am hoping to have a result that holds the number of days each month, row 1: 15, 31, 31, 10. This representing the days in June beginning at from_date thru eom for June, then all of July, all of August and lastly days until to_date.

Which is to apportion the 87 days in the days from each month